# Building Mongoose Schema with indeterminate number of nested objects

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

**1. Sample dashboard menu data:**

```
const dashboards = [
  {"dashboard": "sample",
    "items": [
      { "title": "Title 1" },
      { "title": "Title 2",
        "items": [
          { "title": "Title 2-1",
            "items": [
              { "title": "Title 2-1-1" },
              { "title": "Title 2-1-2" }
            ]
          },
          { "title": "Title 2-2" }
        ]
      },
      { "title": "Title 3",
        "items": [
          { "title": "Title 3-1" },
          { "title": "Title 3-2",
            "items": [
              { "title": "Title 3-2-1" },
              { "title": "Title 3-2-2" }
            ]
          }
        ]      },
      { "title": "Title 4",
        "items": [
          { "title": "Title 4-1" },
          { "title": "Title 4-2",
            "items": [
              { "title": "Title 4-2-1" },
              { "title": "Title 4-2-2",
                "items": [
                  { "title": "Title 4-2-2-1" },
                  { "title": "Title 4-2-2-2" }
                ]              
              }
            ]
          }
        ]      
      }
  ]}
];
```

**2. My schema attempt:**

```
    const DashboardMenuSchema = new Schema({
      title: {type: String},
      items: [{
        title: String
      }]
    }, { _id: true });

    DashboardMenuSchema.add({ items: [DashboardMenuSchema.items] });
```

---

My schema is not working as expected.

What would be the proper approach to satisfy and indeterminate number of menu items?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turns out this was pretty straight forward ....**

```
const ItemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type: String},
});


export const DashboardMenuSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type: String},
  items: [ItemSchema]
}, { _id: true });

DashboardMenuSchema.add({ items: [DashboardMenuSchema.items] });
```